# Migration of javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to migrate javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence and curently I seem to be unable to overcome following error:

```
Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

My dependencies are:

```
org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:3.0.2
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.6.5.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.6.5.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-core-jakarta:5.6.5.Final

jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.1
org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.2.Final
org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-cdi:7.0.2.Final

org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.15
org.springframework:spring-orm:5.3.15
org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.15
org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.15
org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.15
```

Can you lead me to what I am including wrongly?

Comment: can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: is this enough? https://gist.github.com/knyttl/3cad05e16dbfe6957adca4d99ae28b55

Comment: The first Spring version to be Jakartified is 6.0. You're still using 5.3. If you're stuck to Spring (i.e. you cannot migrate to a normal Jakarta EE server as well), then you need to stay with javax.* libs until Spring 6.0 is out.